# Related LinkedIn Target Audience facets

Tags: linkedin-api

i am new this linked-in ad campaign API i am not able to find out which facet combination is correct to achieve the specific targeting audience
and there is no JSON [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0jEW.png)available to figure it out for proper combination
For Example - if i am selecting company_size with other facet i am not able to create LinkedIn campaign with targeting audience.

So i am not able to find out what is combination for linkedIn target audience,

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the example in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-examples), a working example for your scenario is:

```
{
    "include": {
        "and": [{
            "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:staffCountRanges": [
                    "urn:li:staffCountRange:(2,10)"
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:industries": [
                    "urn:li:industry:4",
                    "urn:li:industry:51"
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "or": {
                "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:locations": [
                    "urn:li:country:us"
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I've created a campaign with this targeting and the related targeting audience looks like:

[image: from campaign manager]

Hope this help

NB: [A bug exists in the doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Contribute/issues/219), I didn't remember if the doc was updated

**UPDATE:**

Referring to the doc:

> These facets names and facet values mentioned below are discoverable
>   using the [adTargetingFacets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/adtargetingfacets) and [adTargetingEntities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/adtargetingentities) API.
>
> You can also refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting) for Ads Targeting Discovery.

You can use the explore API in order to find the right key values

Comment: This is working fine but now i want to add age and gender with linkedin target audience i am not able to create linkedin campaign this time

Comment: {
        "or":{
         "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:staffCountRanges": [
              "urn:li:staffCountRange:(2,10)"
            ] 
         }
        },
         {
          "or": {
            "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:ageRanges": [
              "urn:li:agerange:(25",
              "34)"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "or": {
            "urn:li:adTargetingFacet:genders": [
              "urn:li:gender:female"
            ]
          }
        }

Comment: Hi @Learner the ageRange key is invalid, the right value is `"urn:li:ageRange:(25,34)"`  Use the discover API in order to check the right values, as example https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adTargetingEntities?q=adTargetingFacet&queryVersion=QUERY_USES_URNS&facet=urn:li:adTargetingFacet:ageRanges"